# how to consume asmx web serice from android app which returns an object in android app?

Tags: java, android, web-services, asmx

I am new to Android development, I have got some problem when calling asmx web service from my android app.

I am using the following code to call asmx webservices from my android app.

```
                    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

        SoapObject request=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,Method_Name);

        PropertyInfo p=new PropertyInfo();
        p.setName("Item");
        p.setValue(itm);
        p.setType(itm.getClass());
        request.addProperty(p);

           SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new  SoapSerializationEnvelope               (SoapEnvelope.VER12);
        envelope.dotNet=true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "ItemById",new Item().getClass());
        HttpTransportSE androidTSE=new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        androidTSE.call(Soap_Action, envelope);
        SoapObject response=(SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
        itm.ItemId=Integer.parseInt(response.getProperty(0).toString());
        itm.Itemname=response.getProperty(1).toString();
        Log.i("ItemName",itm.Itemname);
        tv.setText(itm.Itemname);
```

when I call the service I am getting Itemname as 0. but the application is running happily in my dotNET app.

What may be the problem? how to know whether does the connection has established or not?

Answer (score 1):

You Replace below method

```
 HttpTransportSE androidTSE=new HttpTransportSE(URL);
```

into

```
 AndroidHttpTransport androidTSE= new AndroidHttpTransport(URL, Timeout);
 androidTSE.debug = true;
 androidTSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```